# Angular.js: Cannot set a custom attribute directive

Tags: angular, attributes, directive

I have ultra-simple code with a directive and a component trying to use it but the code doesn't work. Cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[classSetter]'
})
class classSetter implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() classSetter : string = "";

  el : ElementRef;

  constructor (el : ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  ngOnInit () {
    this.el.nativeElement.classList.add(this.classSetter);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styles: ['.blue {background-color: blue;}'],
  template: `
              <span [classSetter]="'blue'">{{title}}</span>
            `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'directive';
}
```

The error I get is *Can't bind to 'classSetter' since it isn't a known property of 'span'*.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gf1ee4

Please, tell me, what do I miss here?

Comment: Have you provided the directive in provider array either in module or component?

Comment: Yes. And even tried to mention classSetter in imports: [...] of AppComponent where I use it. And still same error.

Comment: can you please provide me with a stackblitz with this code and issue

Comment: Have you tried this; <span classSetter [classSetter]="'blue'"> . Since you have to bind to the input property not the directive itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! Aakash Garg, tried your suggestion and got the same result. Faith Ersoy, here it is!
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gf1ee4

Comment: i cannot see anything on stackblitz you gave

Comment: Aakash Garg, sorry, I don't know, why it doesn't open. Just now the link has opened for me, even though I have logged out. But the problem is solved! Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive needs to go in declarations array of module not the providers array of component decorator. fixed it here as well :-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bz2sez?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: That's right! Thank you so much! :)